# How to pass a json body from ruby to bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, curl

I am trying to study both bash and ruby and I am trying to pass a variable that contains a JSON object from ruby to be printed using a bash script.

I tried storing the JSON object in a variable then used that variable as an argument for my bash script but I am not getting the result that I wanted.

so in my ruby code I have this:

```
param = request.body
cmd = "ruby_to_bash #{param}"
exec cmd
```

and in my bash script, I am simply outputting the value of the argument:

```
echo $1
```

For example I have this JSON:

```
{"first":"one","second":"two","third":"three"}
```

my code only gives me this output:

```
{first:
```

I want to display the whole JSON object. How can I do this? Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both bash and ruby treat double quotes in a kinda special way: double-quoted strings are *interpolated* before passed to the receiver. I strongly encourage you to start with learning somewhat one in the first place instead of doing zero progress in both due to induced errors.

Answering the question stated, one must escape double quotes when passing back and forth since both ruby and bash treat them as *content delimiters* and discard when the content is already parsed in the resulting string.

This would work:

```
exec %|ruby_to_bash #{param.gsub('"', '\"')}|
```

I use `%|` and `|` as string delimiters to avoid clashes against inner quotes.

---

*Sidenote:* the above won’t work for the input containing spaces, but I purposely avoid to show how to deal with spaces since it leads to the dead end; once handled spaces with surrounding the interpolated `param` with single quotes, we are prone to be screwed up with *inner single quotes* in JSON object and so forth.

The code above is not someone should ever produce in production.

Comment: hello @Aleksei, thank you so much for your response however It is still not outputting the whole json object. It just adds a double quote from my previous output

Comment: Sure it does. You must check it on the input you provided for us. If your input is more complicated and contains spaces (which is most likely the case,) you should surround the whole string with single quotes before passing it to shell.

Comment: @Noel : You did not show the code of `ruby_to_bash`, but for your concrete example string, I guess that `cmd = "ruby_to_bash '#{param}"'` will work. Of course it won't work in general (for every JSON) string, and the whole idea of building up a command line and running it with `exec` is flawed. It would be much better if  you would pass the arguments to your script individually; see the documentation for the _exec_ method.

Comment: @user1934428 also a subshell with [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Kernel.html#method-i-system) is magnitudes of order better than replacing the current process with `Kernel#exec`.

Comment: Well, I guess the OP *wants* to replace his process; otherwise he would not have used `exec`. Indeed, if passing the control to the script is the last action to perform, I don't see why he should not do it in his way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is, as usual in such cases, not to involve a shell at all.

When you say this:

```
cmd = "ruby_to_bash #{param}"
exec cmd
```

Your `exec` call is invoking a shell which parses `cmd` and then runs `ruby_to_bash` so you're doing this:

1. Build a command line.
2. Replace the current process with `/bin/sh`.
3. `/bin/sh` parses the command line that you should mashed together. This is where you need to worry about quoting and escaping to get past the shell.
4. `/bin/sh` exec's `ruby_to_bash`.

You could bypass the whole problem by using the multi-argument form of [`Kernel#exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

> **exec(cmdname, arg1, ...)**
>   command name and one or more arguments (no shell)

which doesn't bother with a shell at all. If you say:

```
exec 'ruby_to_bash', param
```

You won't involve a shell and the quotes or spacing in `param` won't matter to anyone other than `ruby_to_bash`.